# Spotfire - refresh Information Link for a report

Tags: spotfire

I have an information link that I use for an itemized report and and summary report of those items.

I updated the information link but the summary report that is based on the original information link still returns data from the original version of the link.

How do I refresh the link used by the report with out rewriting the report?

Comment: As with all things, easy when you know how. Thankyou Sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Edit > Data Table Properties

Select the summary report and click refresh.